# Mount command hanging after attaching EBS volumes on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, btrfs

I'm creating four volumes from four EBS snapshots on AWS. The four volumes make up one BTRFS multi-device drive. The drives have no partition tables, i.e I've ran `mkfs.btrfs /dev/xvdf /dev/xvdg` etc.

When I create the volumes I attach them with the AWS CLI tool then run `btrfs device scan /dev/xvd{f,g,h,i}`. The devices have a label, so to mount them I run (I've tried a few things) `mount -t btrfs -o ro,nospace_cache,clear_cache -L LABEL /tmp/dir`. This hangs for quite a long time, 15-20 minutes. The devices are each 2TB.

When I look in dmesg I see the below messages. While dmesg is hanging, no additional output shows up in dmesg. I am at a loss as to what else to check to see what is causing this hang.

```
[ 3316.093665] blkfront: xvdf: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[ 3316.124269]  xvdf: unknown partition table
[ 3316.430563] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 1 transid 592370 /dev/xvdf
[ 3316.432660] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 1 transid 592370 /dev/xvdf
[ 3317.067647] blkfront: xvdg: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[ 3317.111985]  xvdg: unknown partition table
[ 3317.450861] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 2 transid 592370 /dev/xvdg
[ 3317.453036] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 2 transid 592370 /dev/xvdg
[ 3318.186270] blkfront: xvdh: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[ 3318.232822]  xvdh: unknown partition table
[ 3319.025208] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 3 transid 592370 /dev/xvdh
[ 3319.027380] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 3 transid 592370 /dev/xvdh
[ 3320.067903] blkfront: xvdi: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[ 3320.123265]  xvdi: unknown partition table
[ 3320.495547] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 592370 /dev/xvdi
[ 3320.497922] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 592370 /dev/xvdi
[ 3321.436803] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 1 transid 592370 /dev/xvdf
[ 3321.437252] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 2 transid 592370 /dev/xvdg
[ 3321.437641] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 3 transid 592370 /dev/xvdh
[ 3321.438040] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 592370 /dev/xvdi
[ 3457.266257] blkfront: xvdf: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[ 3457.315871]  xvdf: unknown partition table
[ 3457.862287] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 1 transid 592370 /dev/xvdf
[ 3457.864513] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 1 transid 592370 /dev/xvdf
[ 3458.413241] blkfront: xvdg: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[ 3458.519586]  xvdg: unknown partition table
[ 3458.941200] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 2 transid 592370 /dev/xvdg
[ 3458.943531] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 2 transid 592370 /dev/xvdg
[ 3460.121281] blkfront: xvdh: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[ 3460.198695]  xvdh: unknown partition table
[ 3460.805858] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 3 transid 592370 /dev/xvdh
[ 3460.808173] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 3 transid 592370 /dev/xvdh
[ 3461.146042] blkfront: xvdi: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[ 3461.271872]  xvdi: unknown partition table
[ 3462.355409] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 592370 /dev/xvdi
[ 3462.357822] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 592370 /dev/xvdi
[ 3463.185250] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 1 transid 592370 /dev/xvdf
[ 3463.185669] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 2 transid 592370 /dev/xvdg
[ 3463.186098] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 3 transid 592370 /dev/xvdh
[ 3463.186471] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 592370 /dev/xvdi
[ 3463.217317] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 592370 /dev/xvdi
[ 3463.219230] btrfs: disabling disk space caching
[ 3463.219233] btrfs: force clearing of disk cache
[ 4930.891445] btrfs: device fsid e512929a-72e4-4bf9-bf1d-c4744bb9cb06 devid 2 transid 27031 /dev/xvdb
[ 4930.893685] btrfs: device fsid e512929a-72e4-4bf9-bf1d-c4744bb9cb06 devid 2 transid 27031 /dev/xvdb
[ 4930.949380] btrfs: device fsid e512929a-72e4-4bf9-bf1d-c4744bb9cb06 devid 1 transid 27031 /dev/xvdc
[ 4930.951209] btrfs: device fsid e512929a-72e4-4bf9-bf1d-c4744bb9cb06 devid 1 transid 27031 /dev/xvdc
[ 4937.133509] btrfs: device fsid e512929a-72e4-4bf9-bf1d-c4744bb9cb06 devid 2 transid 27031 /dev/xvdb
[ 4937.135297] btrfs: device fsid e512929a-72e4-4bf9-bf1d-c4744bb9cb06 devid 2 transid 27031 /dev/xvdb
[ 4937.135757] btrfs: device fsid e512929a-72e4-4bf9-bf1d-c4744bb9cb06 devid 1 transid 27031 /dev/xvdc
[ 4937.137575] btrfs: device fsid e512929a-72e4-4bf9-bf1d-c4744bb9cb06 devid 1 transid 27031 /dev/xvdc
```

Edit:

Running `watch iostat -dk 2 -x 1` shows some different numbers, at first it was showing a high utilization on the first two devices, and then shows this:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.01     1.49    0.87    2.99    22.34   274.17   153.71     1.62  419.08    5.06  540.15   3.91   1.51
xvdd              0.00     0.00    0.02    0.00     0.07     0.00     7.91     0.00    0.41    0.41    0.00   0.41   0.00
xvdb              0.00     0.10    1.53    1.59    23.88    31.80    35.69     0.16   52.79    5.00   98.68   2.80   0.87
xvdc              0.00     0.08    1.58    1.37    24.99    27.43    35.49     0.25   84.70    5.21  176.74   3.45   1.02
xvdf              0.00     2.11    0.48   13.36     7.44  1325.75   192.64     2.25  162.64    5.33  168.27   2.18   3.01
xvdt              0.00     0.00    0.01    0.00     0.08     0.00    31.25     0.00   77.77   77.77    0.00  72.35   0.04
xvdy              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.03     0.00    30.32     0.00  102.43  102.43    0.00 101.05   0.02
xvdu              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00    20.96     0.00   75.64   75.64    0.00  75.64   0.00
xvdo              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.01     0.00    16.84     0.00   38.53   38.53    0.00  38.53   0.00
```

This is a snippet of the syslog:

```
Nov 23 17:35:01 ip-10-0-1-123 CRON[11806]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Nov 23 17:38:28 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605946.625013] blkfront: xvdt: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
Nov 23 17:38:28 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605946.732903]  xvdt: unknown partition table
Nov 23 17:38:28 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605947.017249] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 1 transid 616951 /dev/xvdt
Nov 23 17:38:29 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605947.036501] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 1 transid 616951 /dev/xvdt
Nov 23 17:38:30 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605948.575945] blkfront: xvdy: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
Nov 23 17:38:30 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605948.624099]  xvdy: unknown partition table
Nov 23 17:38:30 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605948.944109] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 2 transid 616951 /dev/xvdy
Nov 23 17:38:30 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605948.946964] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 2 transid 616951 /dev/xvdy
Nov 23 17:38:31 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605949.783777] blkfront: xvdu: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
Nov 23 17:38:31 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605949.839874]  xvdu: unknown partition table
Nov 23 17:38:32 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605950.260981] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 3 transid 616951 /dev/xvdu
Nov 23 17:38:32 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605950.263252] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 3 transid 616951 /dev/xvdu
Nov 23 17:38:33 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605951.590060] blkfront: xvdo: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: enabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
Nov 23 17:38:33 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605951.662633]  xvdo: unknown partition table
Nov 23 17:38:33 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605951.950477] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 616951 /dev/xvdo
Nov 23 17:38:33 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605951.953476] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 616951 /dev/xvdo
Nov 23 17:38:35 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605953.098657] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 1 transid 616951 /dev/xvdt
Nov 23 17:38:35 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605953.099002] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 2 transid 616951 /dev/xvdy
Nov 23 17:38:35 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605953.099292] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 3 transid 616951 /dev/xvdu
Nov 23 17:38:35 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605953.099723] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 616951 /dev/xvdo
Nov 23 17:38:35 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605953.135590] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 616951 /dev/xvdo
Nov 23 17:38:35 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605953.137944] btrfs: disabling disk space caching
Nov 23 17:38:35 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605953.137948] btrfs: force clearing of disk cache
Nov 23 17:38:36 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [605954.947400] btrfs: device label BtrFcdData devid 4 transid 616951 /dev/xvdo
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.868106] INFO: task mount:12477 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.871838]       Not tainted 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.874879] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878538] mount           D ffff88020fc13180     0 12477   7218 0x00000000
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878543]  ffff88016d32bc18 0000000000000086 ffff88009bb8e000 0000000000013180
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878547]  ffff88016d32bfd8 0000000000013180 ffff88009bb8e000 ffff88009bb8e000
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878550]  ffff8800776ca870 ffff8800776ca878 ffffffff00000000 ffff8800776ca880
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878553] Call Trace:
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878562]  [<ffffffff8172e2e9>] schedule+0x29/0x70
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878566]  [<ffffffff81730f05>] rwsem_down_write_failed+0x115/0x230
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878571]  [<ffffffff811dd0eb>] ? iput+0x3b/0x180
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878579]  [<ffffffffa00b0000>] ? 0xffffffffa00affff
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878584]  [<ffffffff81377da3>] call_rwsem_down_write_failed+0x13/0x20
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878602]  [<ffffffffa00b51fa>] ? btrfs_mount+0x2ea/0x800 [btrfs]
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878605]  [<ffffffff8173093d>] ? down_write+0x2d/0x30
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878609]  [<ffffffff811c3c7e>] grab_super+0x2e/0xa0
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878611]  [<ffffffff811c42f0>] sget+0x2d0/0x400
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878621]  [<ffffffffa00b29a0>] ? btrfs_parse_early_options+0x1b0/0x1b0 [btrfs]
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878630]  [<ffffffffa00b5328>] btrfs_mount+0x418/0x800 [btrfs]
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878634]  [<ffffffff811735aa>] ? pcpu_alloc+0x6ca/0xa50
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878637]  [<ffffffff8119ad33>] ? alloc_pages_current+0xa3/0x160
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878641]  [<ffffffff811c5149>] mount_fs+0x39/0x1b0
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878644]  [<ffffffff811e0917>] vfs_kern_mount+0x67/0x110
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878648]  [<ffffffff811e31ef>] do_mount+0x25f/0xcd0
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878652]  [<ffffffff81156dae>] ? __get_free_pages+0xe/0x50
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878655]  [<ffffffff811e2e16>] ? copy_mount_options+0x36/0x170
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878658]  [<ffffffff811e3f53>] SyS_mount+0x83/0xc0
Nov 23 17:41:22 ip-10-0-1-123 kernel: [606120.878662]  [<ffffffff8173a9dd>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
```

Comment: Try `iostat -x 1` and see what you see during this "hang."  My guess is you're dealing with a first-touch/warmup issue and you'll see maybe 5 MB/s of I/O and the volume allegedly approaching 100% utilization.

Comment: Please share a snippet of the syslog  when the mount action is initialized

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've added more info

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mount a multi-device filesystem using a loopback device, it's not sufficient to use mount -o loop. Instead, you'll have to set up the loopbacks manually:

## Create and mount a filesystem made of several disk images

1. mkfs.btrfs img0 img1 img2

   losetup /dev/loop0 img0

   losetup /dev/loop1 img1

   losetup /dev/loop2 img2

   mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/btrfs

Comment: I'm not using a loopback device anywhere. These are block devices attached via AWS as /dev/xvd*

Comment: Were you able to resolve this, I have exact issue